# Javascript function call into loop each time

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have function called `rotator(id)`: this function animate `div` and I can called this function with different `id` for animate different elements

Actually I use 5 differents id , `1,2,3,4,5`

And for call I need put :

```
rotador(1);rotador(2);rotador(3);rotador(4);rotador(5);
```

The problem it´s that I want to rotate in automatic mode. For this I think to use this

```
for (i=0;i<=5;i++) { 
   setTimeout(rotador(i),2000);
}
```

But it doesn't work because it animates all in the same time, no let firt execute the first and continue before of first go second , etc , etc and when go the end or number 5 start other time in one

My problem it´s this if you can help me THANKS !!! :) Regards

Answer (score 4):

You are actually calling the rodator(i) function, and schedule for execution after 2 seconds the result of the rodator. In other words, your code is now equalent to:

```
for (i=0;i<=5;i++) { 
   var result = rotador(i);
   setTimeout(result,2000);
}
```

You can accomplish this either by creating a function for the callback:

```
for (i=0;i<=5;i++) { 
   setTimeout((function(i){
      return function(){
        rotador(i);
      }
    })(i),2000 * i);
}
```

or you can call the next rodator in the rotador function itself:

```
var rotador = function(i){
    // your code
    if (i < 5) {
       setTimeout(function(){rotaror(i + 1);}, 2000);
    }
}
```

**Note**: the closure in the second example is needed to call the function with the correct value of `i`. We are creating an anonymous function, and create `i` as a local scope variable, which value won't be mutated by the outerscope changes. (we can rename `i` to `n` in the local scope, if this would be more readable). Otherwise the value of `i` will be 5 each time rotador is called, as the value of `i` would be modified before the actual function call.

Comment: What's the difference between calling `rotador(i)` in the timeout closure and returning it as a new function? I am curious :)

Comment: The value of i. We are returning a function in a new scope, when i is defined with the specific value. If we just call it in a function, it will have the value of i of the outer scope, which will be always the last one - 5 in the case

Answer (score 3):

since setTimeout() does not wait for the function to be executed before continuing, you have to set the delay to a different value for different items, something like `2000 * (i + 1)` instead of just `2000`

EDIT: yes, and you need the callback as Darhazer suggests

Answer (score 1):

```
rotationStep(1);

function rotador(id)
{
    console.log(id);
}

function rotationStep( currentId )
{
    rotador(currentId);
    var nextId = currentId<5 ? currentId+1 : 1;
    setTimeout(function(){ rotationStep(nextId) },2000); //anonymous function is a way to pass parameter in IE
}
```

Comment: Did you remove 

function rotador(id)
{
    console.log(id);
}
?

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    rotador(i)
}, 2000)
```